# Bootstrap form $_POST empty

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to submit an email to subscribe to a newsletter using php and bootstrap. The var_dump($_POST) outputs this: 
array(1) { 'subscribe_submit' => string(0) "" }

This is my html:

```
<form method="post" action="subscribe.php" class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter `enter code here`email" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="subscribe_submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

subscribe.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['subscribe_submit']))
{
// Define $email
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Protect from injection
$email = stripslashes($email);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);

// Check database to see if email is already subscribed

$sql="SELECT id FROM minutes WHERE email='$email'";
$result=$db->query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();

if($result->num_rows == 1)
{
echo "You are already subscribed to our minutes.";
}else
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO minutes (email)
VALUES ($email)";

if ($db->query($sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
}

$db->close();  
}
}
?>
```

I have been racking my brain all day trying to figure out why it is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give your `<input>` element a `name=` attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you forgot the most important attribute `name="email"`

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" 
placeholder="Enter `enter code here`email" required>
```